# TableView section index title size for different dimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]I have used `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` delegate method to create an index for each section on the right side of the `tableview`, everything is working fine but the problem I am facing is when I run this app on `iPhone 5s`, the screen size is small as compared to other screen sizes and alphabetic index on the right is not showing within the screen heigh and few alphabets are out of the screen area and not visible to the user. Can some one please guide how I can control the index heigh on the right side of the table view so it fits in small screen dimensions as well.

```
//Mark - sectionForSectionIndexTitle
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return groupIndexTitles.firstIndex(of: title)!
    }
```

Comment: Hi @AdeelIlyas, please share UI for better understand.

Comment: Hi Emre, i have added a screenshot of iPhone 5s with sample data, please check the index on right as it is not showing fully and alphabets after T are not showing. for bigger dimension there is no issue as screen height is enough to adjust it.

Comment: @AdeelIlyas - it looks like your tableView is not constrained properly, and is extending below the bounds of the screen.

Comment: Thanks DonMag, you are right, mistakenly I added the constraint constant below zero. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

OS will automatically truncate your array if it's too long. For example, if you view your contact list in portrait orientation you will see a full index A-Z but when you rotate to landscape you'll see A * D * .... and so on.
You can't size.
But you can create custom tableview and integrate custom index view.